# ENOTFOUND issue on https get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

In my application I'm trying to hit an end point using https and then getting the response.

Route file:

```
router.get("/get-details", (req, res) => {
  sampleController.getDetails()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Data is ", data);
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        data: null,
        message: "Failed to lookup the data",
      });
    });
});
```

Controller file:

```
const getDetials = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      hostname: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
      path: "posts",
      method: "GET",
    };

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

      res.on("data", (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
      });
    });

    req.on("error", (error) => {
      console.log("Error is ", error);
      reject(error);
    });

    req.end();
  });
};
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

Not sure where I'm making the mistake. Does somebody know what I'm getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up the URL without the protocol and add `/` in front of the path in options object:

```
 const options = {
      hostname: "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
      path: "/posts",
      method: "GET",
    };
```

Full example:

```
const getDetials = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      hostname: "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
      path: "/posts",
      method: "GET",
    };

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

      res.on("data", (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
      });
    });

    req.on("error", (error) => {
      console.log("Error is ", error);
      reject(error);
    });

    req.end();
  });
};
```